# My webcam is not configured correctly

Tags: drivers, webcam

On my laptop I have a built in webcam. It is an Acer Crystal Eye. Since a couple months ago my webcam has stopped working, and I have no idea how to get it started again. Sometime ago someone told me it may be configured as a keyboard, but I didn't get anywhere with that. I have tried a lot of the popular answers on other questions but to no avail. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you try an application, as VLC, Cheese, Record My Desktop, etc?? For default, Ubuntu don't have an direct acces to the Webcam and microphone, so you need an application to access to this hardware.

In the case of the webcam, the most common is Cheese (but I say others examples) and for the microphone I recomend Audacity